# AsyncStorage react native can't getItem

Tags: javascript, react-native, authentication, token, asyncstorage

This is my code:

```
AsyncStorage.getItem('idtoken').then(value => console.log(value));
```

and this is result:

`eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6NTEsImlhdCI6MTYwMzc5ODUyM30.d8veMJVBhYA9P_JAvfpOOMbuZxvMATyrHpzQBaXPHyg`

But when I try :

```
 const getTaken = () => AsyncStorage.getItem('idtoken').then(value => {
    var tokenuser = value;
    return tokenuser;
  });
  token = getTaken();
  console.log(token);
```

the result is:   `{"_U": 0, "_V": 0, "_W": null, "_X": null}`

How can I get the value stored in idtoken, please help me

Comment: did any answer solve your problem? please provide some feedback

Answer (score 0):

You can store and get Data with this functions:

```
  const storeData = async (key, value) => {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem(key, value); 
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  const getData = async key => {
    try {
      const data = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);
      if (data !== null) {
        console.log(data);
        return data;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

Then you can call the functions and get the values like this:

Store the value:

```
storeData("Keyname", the value);
```

Get the value and set it as state for example:

```
  await getData"Keyname") 
    .then((data) => data)
    .then((value) => this.setState({ isFavorite: value }))
    .catch((err) => console.log("AsyncStorageErr: " + err));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
const getTaken = async () => {    

    return await AsyncStorage.getItem("idtoken")
}

const token = getTaken();
console.log(token);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are defining `getTaken` as a function that resolves to a promise. In order to correct call it, you need to say that it is a async function, by doing:

```
const getTaken = **async** () => AsyncStorage.getItem('idtoken').then(value => {
    var tokenuser = value;
    return tokenuser;
  });
```

Then, you cant get the results of it by adding await before calling it.

```
token = **await** getTaken();`enter code here`
```